# How to clear input field on button click in Ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic 1. The problem is click on Submit button the input fields doesn't clear. On button click after posting data to server it reloads the same page but with already entered fields.

**html**

```
     <div style="margin-left: 20px;margin-right: 20px;margin-top: 55px;"> 
        <div class = "list">
           <label class = "item item-input item-stacked-label">
           <!-- <span class = "input-label">Name</span> -->
           <input type = "text" placeholder = "Name" required ng-model="name" clearInput="true"/>
           </label>
        </div>
        <div class = "list">
           <label class = "item item-input item-stacked-label">
           <!-- <span class = "input-label">Mobile Number</span> -->
           <input type = "tel"maxlength="10" clearInput="true" placeholder = "Mobile No." pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" required ng-model="mobile" />
           </label>
        </div>
        <div class="padding text-right" style="margin-top: -12px;">
           <button class="button button-positive " ng-click="enter(name,mobile)" style="width: 100%;">
           Submit
           </button>
        </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

**js**

```
$scope.enter = function (name,mobile) {
                if (name == null) {
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        template: 'Please Enter Name!'
                    });

                } else if (mobile == null) {
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        template: 'Please Enter Mobile Number!'
                    });

                }
                 else  {
        $ionicLoading.show({
                    template: '<ion-spinner></ion-spinner><p>Loading...</p>'
                          });
       var link = 'http://mountsystem/mobileapi/coreapi.php';
            var datasend = $.param({
                request_code: 'demo_attendance',
                batch_id:$stateParams.batchId,
                mobile_no: mobile,
                student_name: name,
                franchise_id: $scope.userDetails.franchise_id,
                entered_by:$scope.userDetails.employee_id
        });
        console.log(datasend);
        $http.post(link, datasend, config)
                .success(function (response) {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response.response_code == 'STATUS_OK') {
                        $scope.list = response;
                        console.log($scope.list);                             
                        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                          title: 'Hurrayy',
                          content: 'Successfully Submitted !'
                        })

                    } else {

                        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                            title: 'Error!',
                            template: response.msg
                        });
                    }
                }).error(function (response) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'ServerError!',
                template: 'ServerError' + response
            });
        });
}}
```

I just want as soon as I click submit button both input fields (username and mobile number) will be clear so that I again entered new details.

Comment: just add at the end of function - name=''; mobile='';

Comment: Not working Sir !

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the name and telephone variables to "" in your .js file. It will clear the fields in the front.

Also why are you still using Ionic 1. I recommend moving to Ionic 3, waiting the fourth version to be really stable.

Comment: Yeah i am working on Ionic 3.I have an app that build on ionic 1 and i have some changes in that that's why using ionic 1.

Answer (score 0):

Change ng-model variable with below code

```html
 <div style="margin-left: 20px;margin-right: 20px;margin-top: 55px;"> 
        <div class = "list">
           <label class = "item item-input item-stacked-label">
           <!-- <span class = "input-label">Name</span> -->
           <input type = "text" placeholder = "Name" required ng-model="data.name" clearInput="true"/>
           </label>
        </div>
        <div class = "list">
           <label class = "item item-input item-stacked-label">
           <!-- <span class = "input-label">Mobile Number</span> -->
           <input type = "tel"maxlength="10" clearInput="true" placeholder = "Mobile No." pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" required ng-model="data.mobile" />
           </label>
        </div>
        <div class="padding text-right" style="margin-top: -12px;">
           <button class="button button-positive " ng-click="enter(data.name,data.mobile)" style="width: 100%;">
           Submit
           </button>
        </div>
 </div>
```

```js
$scope.data = {};

$scope.enter = function (name,mobile) {
                if (name == null) {
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        template: 'Please Enter Name!'
                    });

                } else if (mobile == null) {
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        template: 'Please Enter Mobile Number!'
                    });

                }
                 else  {
        $ionicLoading.show({
                    template: '<ion-spinner></ion-spinner><p>Loading...</p>'
                          });
       var link = 'http://mountsystem/mobileapi/coreapi.php';
            var datasend = $.param({
                request_code: 'demo_attendance',
                batch_id:$stateParams.batchId,
                mobile_no: mobile,
                student_name: name,
                franchise_id: $scope.userDetails.franchise_id,
                entered_by:$scope.userDetails.employee_id
        });
        console.log(datasend);
        $http.post(link, datasend, config)
                .success(function (response) {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response.response_code == 'STATUS_OK') {
                        $scope.list = response;
                        console.log($scope.list);
                        $scope.data.mobile = '';
                         $scope.data.name = '';                 
                        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                          title: 'Hurrayy',
                          content: 'Successfully Submitted !'
                        })

                    } else {

                        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                            title: 'Error!',
                            template: response.msg
                        });
                    }
                }).error(function (response) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'ServerError!',
                template: 'ServerError' + response
            });
        });
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am quite amazed with the solution but this solution worked for me, the problem was instead of setting a value directly inside `$scope` object, I was supposed to put it within any object of $scope object like this

`<input type="text" placeholder="Enter new todo" ng-model="data.newtodo">` first change model of input field to like this

and in my controller, on top

`$scope.data = {};`

and after success callback

`$scope.data.newtodo = "";`